# Alternative Names for C# enum

Tags: c#, enums

In Java, we can declare `enums` like so

```
public enum ChangeFlag
{
    NEW("New"),
    DELETED("Deleted"),
    REVISED("Revised");

    private final String    text;

    ChangeFlag(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Is there any elegant equivalent to this for C#?

Edit:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
public static string GetDescription(this Foo @this)
{
    switch (@this)
    {
        case Foo.Bar:
            return "A bar";
    }
}
```

}

Could you explain what the parameters in GetDescription(this Foo @this) mean?
I'm not used to seeing what `this Foo @this` refers to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DescriptionAttribute`:

```
public enum Foo
{
    [Description("A bar")]
    Bar
}
```

Which you would then extract via [`TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3a7b50.aspx) or [`Type.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx).

Or you could use extension methods:

```
public enum Foo
{
    Bar
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Foo @this)
    {
        switch (@this)
        {
            case Foo.Bar:
                return "A bar";
        }
    }
}

// consuming code
var foo = Foo.Bar;
var description = foo.GetDescription();
```

The latter approach also gives you more control when it comes to localization, since you could always look up the description in a resource file, for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChangeFlag changeFlag = ChangeFlag.REVISED;
        Console.WriteLine(changeFlag.GetDescription());
        Console.Read();
    }

    public enum ChangeFlag
    {
        [Description("New")]
        NEW,
        [Description("Deleted")]
        DELETED,
        [Description("Revised")]
        REVISED
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A compact and fault-proof implementation variant, of the enum description getter extension method:

```
/// <exception cref="AmbiguousMatchException">More attributes found. </exception>
/// <exception cref="TypeLoadException">Cannot load custom attribute.</exception>
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string enumName = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (enumName == null)
    {
        return null; // or return string.Empty;
    }
    FieldInfo typeField = type.GetField(enumName);
    if (typeField == null)
    {
        return null; // or return string.Empty;
    }
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeField, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
    return (attribute as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description; // ?? string.Empty maybe added
}
```

Also a comparison extension method (which uses the upper) for the description may be useful:

```
public static bool DescriptionEquals(this Enum value, string inputForComparison,
    StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    string description;
    try
    {
        description = value.GetDescription();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is AmbiguousMatchException || ex is TypeLoadException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (description == null || inputForComparison == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return inputForComparison.Equals(description, comparisonType);
    //  || inputForComparison.Equals(value.ToString(), comparisonType); may be added
}
```