# How is this implementation called and is it "right"?

Tags: c#, enums, static

I thought of an enum with variables. Like a prefab object for a class with specific values. I came up with this:

```
public class myClass {

string name;
int number;

public static myClass Version1 = new myClass("test",1);
public static myClass Version2 = new myClass("notest",2);

public myClass(string name, int number)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

}
```

And now I can access the predefined objects from other classes.

Does it have a special name? Is it how an enum works? Is there a better way to do it?

I'm curious and would appreciate help.

Comment: Seems like that its being called Strongly Typed Enum Pattern http://geekswithblogs.net/TimothyK/archive/2014/07/31/strongly-typed-enum-pattern.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of "is there a better way to do it", perhaps this is helpful...

I can't tell what exactly you want to accomplish, but C# has some rich capabilities built into it.  You should research the below, learn about other patterns that might exist, and apply the best ones to your project.

```
public enum Versions
{
    Test = 1,
    [Description("No Test!!")]
    NoTest = 2
}

// NOTE: this function taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625488/alternative-names-for-c-sharp-enum
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enum Test has name of {Enum.GetName(typeof(Versions), Versions.Test)} and a value of {(int)Versions.Test}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Enum NoTest has description of {EnumExtensions.GetDescription(Versions.NoTest)} and a value of {(int)Versions.NoTest}");

        return;
```

Produces:

```
Enum Test has name of Test and a value of 1
Enum NoTest has description of No Test!! and a value of 2
```